# Host key validation failed

Tags: php, git, ssh

I have create a key ssh on my server et added on Github.

When i use the the webhook which call a php page on my seveur with

```
<?php `git pull`;
```

The error.log of apache said me :;Host key validation failed.

I try to resolve it by this link
https://askubuntu.com/questions/45679/ssh-connection-problem-with-host-key-verification-failed-error

```
ssh-keygen -R github.com
```

But it's continue to doesn't work.

Do you have a suggestion?

Comment: My key fingerprint is not the same than on github, how change?

Comment: I don't understand, when i try ssh -T git@github.com: i have this message : Hi ArmandArthur/santa-apolonia! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access. Normally it's good but i have always the same error, when i take ssh github.com i have Permission denied (publickey).

Answer (score 0):

> Host key validation failed

Means that the server host key is not trusted (which is sane -- there is no way to verify that key from a script -- you should do that manually).

Go to the [GitHub documentation](https://help.github.com/articles/github-s-ssh-key-fingerprints/), where you can see the fingerprints you will be verifying.

Then change to this user running the script (`apache`?) for example using sudo and run `ssh github.com`. It will prompt you to verify the fingerprints. If they match, write yes and then you script should pass.